# Making post appear Newest to Oldest on a blog page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP code that posts the articles I have made, but from Oldest to Newest and I need it to be Newest to Oldest, so the order is the issue

[The inside of the "posts" row inside my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Ods.png)

This is the function I am using to put the posts in an array:

```
function getPublishedPosts() {
    // use global $conn object in function
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE published=true";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    // fetch all posts as an associative array called $posts
    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    return $posts;
}
```

And this is the visual part of the code:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <div class="post" style="margin-left: 0px;">
        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL . '/static/' . $post['image']; ?>" class="post_image" alt="">
        <a href="single_post.php?post-slug=<?php echo $post['slug']; ?>">
            <div class="post_info">
                <h3><?php echo $post['title'] ?></h3>
                <div class="post-body-div">
                    <?php echo html_entity_decode($post['body']); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <span><?php echo date("F j, Y ", strtotime($post["created_at"])); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Research sorting in SQL ... See `ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use SQL query to order by created_at.
replace your function like this.

```
function getPublishedPosts() {
    // use global $conn object in function
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE published=true order by created_at desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    // fetch all posts as an associative array called $posts
    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just reverse the array holding your posts using array_reverse

```
<?php foreach (array_reverse($posts) as $post): ?>
```

http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-reverse.php

(Better would be of course ordering the SQL using ORDER BY, but we need more information about the available database fields.)

Comment: Better to sort the result in SQL as a `SELECT *` returned rows in any order

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are absolutely right, just added something like this to my answer... :)

Comment: @microelements when you say "database fields" do you mean the tables/rows? If yes, then i only have the one I showed and a user one, to set up an admin role

Comment: @MisterSalass look at the top voted answer by joy - this is the way to do it. I just read too quickly and didn't recognize the existing field "created_at" which could be suitable for your sorting needs.

Comment: @microelements I sure did, but still thanks for your answer as well, good sir